# Simplify Yang-Mills Equation of Motion in the 1-form gauge field $A$

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory, gauge-theory, yang-mills, classical-field-theory

We know the Yang-Mills theory Equation of Motion  (eom) without source

$$
* D * F  = * (d (* F ) +  [A,   (* F )])=  0.
$$

> My question is that what are the most simple form we can boil down this eom to its minimal?

$$
* (d (* (d A + A \wedge A)  ) +  [A,   (* (d A + A \wedge A) )])
$$

$$=* d * d A  + * d * (A \wedge A) +A(  * (d a + A \wedge A) ) - (*  (dA + A \wedge A) ) A=0
$$

> This is what I get. How can we massage it further in order to make it as simple as possible but similar to the Maxwell's ---
>
> $$
> * d * d A + ... =0?
> $$
> What is the simplest form of $ ...$ term?

p.s. What I got so far is that
$ ...$ term is
$$C=* d * (A \wedge A) +A(  * (d a + A \wedge A) ) - (*  (dA + A \wedge A) ) A.$$ Do we have better way to simplify this complicated $C$  in terms of $A$?

Comment: $\star d \star dA$ is not gauge invariant, so why do you want to isolate it?

Comment: $F$ is also not gauge invariant, but only covariant. I want to see $C just for comparing the higher order terms.

Comment: $F$ transforms homogeneously so it's much easier to understand than $\star d \star A$.